# PHP message sends "undefined"

Tags: php, email

I have mail.php which sends out an email. This is the code I'm using.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Your Results!';
$message = $_POST['message'];    
$headers = 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
//header("Location: thankyou.php");
echo $message;
}
?>
```

The contents of the email is supposed to the .innerText of of a div I have on my index.php page. If I echo out the message, then the output appears the page (mail.php) but when I comment/uncomment the necessary parts to email myself the message I receive is just "undefined".

Is $message not defined?

Here is the form and javascript I'm using

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="this.message.value = document.getElementById('box').innerText;">
<input type="email" name="email" required>
<input id="content" type="hidden" name="message" value="">   
<input type="submit" name="submit">    
</form>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is causing the error

Comment: PHP never turns an undefined variable into the string `undefined` -- it just converts it to an empty string. So this must be happening in the JS on the client. I can't explain why it's not happening when you do `echo $message`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Change `.innerText` to `.textContent`. `.innerText` is a nonstandard property that doesn't exist in Firefox.

I don't know why you didn't have the same problem when used `echo $message` in the PHP script, unless you tested that version of the script with a different browser (always try to minimize the number of differences when you're testing like this).